# What is the difference between a quay and a wharf?

Tags: differences, nouns

A "wharf" is "an area like a wide wall built near the edge of the sea or a river where ships can be tied and goods can be taken off them," says the Cambridge Online Dictionary.

A "quay" is "a long structure, usually built of stone, where boats can be tied up to take on and off their goods," says the same dictionary.

Does size matter here? I mean, ships for wharves, and boats for quays? Because, apart from that, I can see no real difference.

Answer (score 2):

The Merriam-Webster Unabridged definition of *[wharf](http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/wharf)* (probably paywalled) contains a **Synonym Discussion** that notes (emphases and formatting mine):

> - *wharf*, probably the oldest of the terms applies to any structure *projecting from the shore*
> - *quay* normally applies to wharves or piers *characteristic of small places*
> - a *quay* is a docking facility at which ships lie *parallel to the shoreline*

So: a quay *is a* wharf, but one constructed in a small place, in such a way that ships docked at it lie parallel to the shore.

Answer (score 1):

"*Quay*" and "*wharf*" are originally different in usage only really. A "*wharf*" is for the commercial unloading and loading of ships and is (usually) private property belonging to a shipping company. A "*quay*" is for smaller ships or boats and is available for general use, these are frequently owned and operated by the local governments/councils for the benefit of local fishermen originally. Passenger ships would usually dock at "*quays*", cargo ships at "*wharves*".

A "*wharf*" -

### [image]

A "*quay*" -

[image]

Comment: Someone needs to get those seals unloaded!

Comment: Yes, this is the origin but in modern times the distinction has broken down (I think this is what you are trying to say in your opening sentences).  I’d actually more often refer to the second picture as a “marina” being a place for the permanent docking of yachts and other pleasure craft.